# Is there any ways to set validators to fields in form array?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I try set and clear Validators on fields in form array depends on value of a field in the parent form group but I don't have an idea how to do it because my child form group in the form array is initialized when a function called.

Here is my code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.injuryFoundForm = this.fb.group({
        isDetail: false,
        details: this.fb.array([
            this.initDetail()
        ])
    });

    this.injuryFoundForm.get('isDetail').valueChanges
        .subscribe(checkedValue => {
            /** I need help here
             *
             * const details= this.injuryFoundForm.get('details');
             * checkedValue ? details.clearValidators():
             *                details.setValidators(Validators.required);
             * details.updateValueAndValidity();
             */
        }
}

initDetail(){
    return this.fb.group({
        a: [null, Validators.required], // <- Only this field change validators
        b: null
    });
}
```

It may be simple but I am new angular developer so sorry for my question and thanks for helping